# Drupal search module

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6

Does anyone know how to remove markup from the theme search box? It produces a lot of extra DIVs and CSS id's.

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy thing to do.

First, search your theme (/sites/all/themes/yourtheme). Do you have search-block-form.tpl.php? If so, you can edit it according to your own fashion.

If you don't have search-block-form.tpl.php, you can create it. Follow the very simple instruction in: http://www.bananatools.com/drupal/customizing-search-block-form.html to create it and afterwards change it as you like.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, modifying template variables. Thanks a lot for the link :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you installed a custom theme, go to `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme` and edit the `.tpl.php` and `.css` files. If you didn't install a custom theme, you can't re-theme it without making a huge mess.

Comment: re-theming the search form block or any other part in Drupal is VERY easy. even in existing theme. See my answer for reference.